# Is there a validator to validate a list of Integers? private List<Integer> status;

Tags: spring, bean-validation

I need to prevent XSS attacks using Spring validators.  Is there an annotation for validating a list of Integers?

```
@Digits(integer=1, fraction=0)
private List<Integer> status;
```

private List status;

To prevent an XSS attack but using @Digits didn't work.  I got this error: Exception Occured: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.util.List

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the constraint annotation this way:

```
private List<@Digits(integer=1, fraction=0) Integer> status;
```

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with XSS: no one can possibly inject a script by inserting invalid integers into a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but IntelliJ is reporting this error: '@Digits' is not applicable to type use.

Comment: That means you have an old version of the bean validation API. I tested it on a Spring Boot 2.1.4 (which uses bean validation 2.0.1) test, and it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Hi,

I updated my pom file with the jar but it didn’t fix the error.  Do I need another dependency?

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ArraySchema(minItems = 0, maxItems = 10, schema = @Schema(minimum = "1", maximum = "1000"))
private List<Integer> status;
```

- minItems & maxItems = validating the number of items in the List.
- minimum & maximum = validating the max and min value possible for each Integer item in the List.